# swap inventory sizes or swap inventory size

Tags: grammar

His character swapped inventory sizes with another character. (his character swapped his inventory size (20 slots) with another character's inventory size (15 slots), now his character can't hold as many items)

I am not sure if sizes is correct. Isn't it an uncountable? But in the context of a video game, maybe it makes sense.

Comment: Google Books has dozens of written instances of plural [*he swapped **shirts** with {another player}*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+swapped+shirts+with%22), but none at all for the singular [*... swapped **shirt** with...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+swapped+shirt+with%22). Note that the singular works fine if the noun is preceded by a determiner (***a*** or ***the***, but possessives such as ***his*** work the same here). So *He swapped **the shirt** with John*, and *She swapped **her inventory size** with / for mine* are both syntactically fine.

Comment: Also note that you can swap something ***with** [someone else, who **has** something you want OR with **the thing itself** that you want]*. Or to avoid confusion, you can swap something ***for** [the thing you want]*, because that preposition only links to the thing wanted, not the person who currently has it.